# Arduino Load Cell Limitations

Tags: arduino, load-cell

I came across this forum in my research on load cells for a project at work. I had order the load cell and an amplifier/display but turns out there's no way for the display to show lbs it only shows kg. The load cell I ordered is a 5 ton load cell. The bridge/excitation voltage is 10V DC. Would there be any issues with using this big of a load cell with the Arduino? Most of what I find are smaller load cells. Thank you for your input. If any other information is needed about the load cell I can provide

Comment: The Arduino does not care what size the load cell is. If you get yourself a hx711 load cell interface board and use 5V as the load cell excitation. The impact of using 5V instead of 10V for the excitation means your measurements are moved closer to the noise floor. This might be a problem if you want very fine resolution. Hopefully this will move you in the required direction.

Comment: I was looking into those as a possibility to help me move forward. I don't think the resolution is going to be very fine regardless. This is going onto a piece of farm equipment to measure downward force and going over the land it is probably going to be bouncy any ways. Thank you for the information